# Unit test React component, the material UI dialog component yields error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined "

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I am developing a React app with [Material UI](https://mui.com/) package.

I have created a material Dialog :

```
import { Dialog, DialogTitle, DialogContent, DialogContentText, DialogActions, Button } from '@mui/material';

type Props = {
    open: boolean;
    setOpen: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<any>>;
    myAsyncTask: () => Promise<{ readonly status: string }>;
};

export const MyCustomDialog: React.FC<Props>  = ({ open, setOpen, myAsyncTask }) => { 


    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    return <Dialog aria-labelledby='My Dialog' open={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)}>
        <DialogTitle>My dialog</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText>{`Do you agree on the terms?`}</DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>No</Button>
            <Button onClick={async () => { await myAsyncTask(); setOpen(false); }}>Yes</Button>
        </DialogActions>

    </Dialog>;
}
```

The above `MyCustomDialog` is shown in my main component:

```
export const TokensTabViewContent: React.FC<props> = ({...}) => {
 const [openConfirmDialog, setOpenConfirmDialog] = useState(false);

 return <>
      <MyCustomDialog
        open={openConfirmDialog}
        setOpen={setOpenConfirmDialog}
        myAsyncTask={async ()=> await postMyHttpRequest()} />
      <DataTable
      ... />
 </>

}
```

I would like to unit test the React project, so I am using this [React Testing library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/react). my test is :

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
...
it('should render', async () => {
        // render my main component
        render(<MyMainComp />)

        // the actual test is about the text showing on MyMainComp, not dialog
        const userIdTxt = screen.getByText('user id');
        expect(userIdTxt).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
```

When run above test, I got error:

```
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'MuiDialog-root')]
```

The error is obviously for complaining about the Dialog component. But I don't know why it gives this error, what is `undefined`?

I tried setting breakpoints at every line of the `MyCustomDialog` code, don't see any property there is `undefined`. Anyone could give some ideas?

Comment: You might need to mock Dialog component.

Comment: @sandiprana do you have any example how to mock that? Sorry I am not experienced with React testing.

Comment: Please update your question with full code for the tested components.

Comment: Can you show your `tsconfig.json` and possible folder structure?

Comment: While I am unsure of the answer, I did notice that the open and setOpen variables names are being overshadowed in the dialogComponent (It's used in props and then overridden by the useState)

It might be worth trying to simply comment out the dialog component and see if the error persists. 

Also, I'm unsure of what produces the "user id" text string. Is it produced by the result of the async method? If so, it might we worth triggering it and awaiting it.

Comment: Hey, can you provide more information so that someone can reproduce the issue on their system and help you out I tried to reproduce the issue but I can't still I'll share my demo repo where the test case passed successfully
https://github.com/hrusikeshswain/TypescriptDemo